Can anyone spot the problem with this Tinkcad transimpedance amplifier?
Click the button to simulate it.
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/8RBDSkPU9Kg-transimpedance-amplifier-
The feedback resistor is currently 1 mega ohm, but it doesn't seem to matter. If I use a different value, I still measure about the same voltage on the output of the op-amp to ground. Theoretically I understand the voltage should be Rf multiplied by the current of the photodiode. The Tinkercad diode seems to deliver 100 micro-amps at 100% light, so I would expect 100V in this particular case. I've also tried much smaller resistor values. Can anyone see what the issue is with this system?

The ground of the power supply breadboard is not connected to the op-amp circuit ground. I looked at the circuit for quite a while before I noticed it. I've updated the Tinkercad file with the missing connection,and the system simulated in line with what I expected.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The schematic from the web page:

This schematic does not appear to match the cartoon wiring diagram, which appears to have a split supply, but with things not properly connected. I don't use TinkerCAD (or any other Autodesk product), fwiw.
You are not going to get negative output voltages without a negative supply. There also needs to be a path for current from the non-inverting input.
The BOM indicates a 741 is being used, which is non-ideal but you should be able to get some functionality.
If you connect the V+ to +15V (and only to there), V- to -15V (and only to there), ground the non-inverting input (to the common of the two supplies) along with one side of the PD you should be able to get some life out of it. Flip the PD if you want mostly positive voltage out.
See the below schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thank you for the answer. I'm afraid it's a little confusing to me. I don't understand the issue with the split power supply because: 1. The multi-meters do show +15V and -15V going into the power supply of the op-amp. 2: The power supply is a model of my actual power supply I use on the bench with other op-amp circuits that do function. Lastly the first thing I learned about op-amps is "There is no current flowing through either of the inputs of the op-amp".

Though I do see and issue with the power supply. The ground is not connected to breadboard on the right. LOL.

Yes. Though I don't know your schematic can not match the simulation, some kind of Tinkertoy thing I guess. See the above schematic and  simulation (10uA represents the PD current), and note the non-inverting terminal connections too, please.

I see now. Thanks. Also, thanks for the circuit lab introduciton. I will check that out as well in addition to TinkerCad.

@TomMoore  LTspice is another option that has a great deal of community support and is completely free to download and use as much as you want. There are others that are prettier or cost more, but for now LTspice is very good. KiCAD has ngspice built in and will eventually have a lot of support.

That's also very helpful. I'm working on a DIY scanning tunneling microscope, and the electronics are outside my area of expertise for sure.

Good luck with it- seems others have had some good results.
